Guardian Post analysis error in Binskin tool
In the onebranch build pipeline the tasks are completed without any errors. But while checking the guardian post analysis got the error. I tried to upgrade the nuget version also checked with many steps. But I am unable to get the things.

Please can anyone help me unblock this error? I totally have no idea


Please share the completed YAML of your pipeline. 2. Please enable verbose logs and trigger the pipeline again, then share the detailed error message. Please don't only share the screenshot of the error.

